# How to wait for the post back in Watin?

Tags: c#, web, watin

In my C# code, I am using `Watin` to navigate the web, to log in to a page, I need to click the log in button, but right after I want to log out, so I have the click log out button right after, but the log out part doesn't work. I even tried closing the browser (using the close method) after logging in, but it didn't work. It feels like as soon as the page gets changed (i.e. after logging in) no more commands from the c# will work.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer Thread.Sleep(milliseconds) is a way to wait for a time period for something to load.  Very, very easy to implement, but it is far from optimal due to varying load times, and if you make it long enough so that it will always wait long enough you'll end up with a lot of wasted time.  On one test this is not a big deal, but for instance if you have to wait 5 seconds and you have 1000 tests.... etc etc etc.

The route I've gone is:

1. Put in Thread.Sleep()s to determine if it is a "wait" issue.
2. If the the code with the Sleep() is going to be used more than once figure out what is causing the need for the sleep().
3. Refactor out the Sleep() using various Wait...() methods.  WaitTilExists, WaitForAttributeEqualsWhatever, WaitForAsyncToFinish   <-  Not real methods, but WatiN has a bunch built in

The big cause of waits for me now is JQuery asynchronous calls in ASP.NET and I made a static helper class that works well for me to wait for async calls to finish.  These tend to be very specific to what framework(s) the sites you're testing are written in.

Answer (score 0):

The watin click command wait until the browser is loaded so practically it wait for the postback.
In case if you using ClickNoWait() command it will not wait.
So if your code looks like this it should work:

```
browser.GoTo("www.your-site.com");
// fill user/pass
browser.Button(Find.ByClass("login-class")).Click();
browser.Button(Find.ByClass("logout-class")).Click();
```

In case it's still not working you can add this after login click **browser.WaitForComplete();**

Answer (score 0):

In Watin you will encounter many situations where the code is non blocking (you'll execute a line of code and will immediately keep going) so for those cases you'll need to find a different way to know that the next page (action, etc.) is already there. For example, on a login page you could check if that pages has a TextBox called UserName:

```
<code>      
    TextField uName = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("userName"));    
    if(uName.Exists)
    {
         // Then do the login code....
    }
</code>
```

In the same way you should control that the page after the login is there before you keep going executing your code. So for example, if you are logging in into a page that you know that will contain the text: "Your Account Details" you might do something like this:

```
<code>
    browser.GoTo("http://www.yourdomain.com/login.aspx");
    //do your login code

    browser.WaitUntilContainsText("Your Account Details", 240); // the second parameter indicates the seconds it will wait before it times out.

    // your code to deal with the page after the login.  
</code>
```

Using Thread.Sleep is a recipe for confusion and that's a problem for sure, you will NEVER get the timing right with a web page (even if you think it will take 10 seconds it might never come back and at that point the server will be terminating the opened connection).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use Thread.sleep in your scripts to sync with logout and login... 
or
instead of logout you directly close application and use ie instance to relogin to application

Comment: OCary, You are right but few times Thread.Sleep has to be used in scenarios like stated in question. If website is giving unpredictable response time.

Comment: Especially if there unpredictable response times, you want to wait on what is taking time to load, not wait an arbitrary length of time.  I've removed significant amounts of execution time from test suites by waiting on the correct item rather than using sleep()s.